# I trying to run android studio but have grade syn error. There are five errors of dependency, debugging. What is the solution

Tags: android-studio

I am using android 3.1.4 and grade version I have tried 4.4 4.5 4.10 and the latest one 5.6.2 but none of them seem to help. The latest version shows some others errors though. What is the solution?

Comment: Maybe you should update Android Studio and disable Gradle Offline mode if it enabled.

Comment: I had downloaded the latest version but couldn't locate the design view. Do you where is the design view in the latest version of android studio?

Comment: The design view and text view both appear on opening the layout xml file

Answer (score 0):

For min api 21 and target 28, I have the following settings my build.gradle(Module:app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yourprojectname"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
     core:3.0.1'

}
```

If you have a different min api level, change the property minSdkVersion to your api and sync online again. Hope this helps.